# Manage different codebases (github repos) by npm (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, developer-tools

I have a scenario in mind which I need to implement with best practices.

**Scenario:-** In our corporation there are multiple teams working on nodejs projects. But, there is one master project which everyone needs to use before starting their project. This master contains must have code which does user auth, heath check, analytics etc. that everyone will be using and then each team can put their code/skills on top of the master code.

How to make master project in nodejs and make it available to use for others.

**Options I can think:-**
1) Create a master project as npm module? or use npm-registry?
2) If 1 is true then is it possible to make our npm project private to my company? Meaning, outside world won't be able to use it by doing 'npm install {masterPro}'
3) Any other best recommendations ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to **fork** an existing Github repo as a basis for starting a new project. This allows you to start with the same code but save future changes as part of a new repository without affecting the original you forked from.

More information here: [Fork a repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/)

Comment: This question was specific to nodejs and node modules management my private registry.
1) Not sure why my tags are removed
2) I think my question is misunderstood.

Comment: How is your 'master' Node.js project stored? How do teams get a copy of this to base their own projects on it?

Comment: Mast project is simple github repo.

How do teams get a copy of this to base their own projects on it?
ans:- this is what I am trying to find. How to achieve this?

Comment: If there is an existing Github repo with the core functionality, you should fork it to create a copy as the core functionality of a seperate project. This creates a new repo with a copy of the master code, and commits to the fork are treated as a new project.